# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration for Kubernetes Flink Session Job

Tags: java, kubernetes, hadoop, apache-flink, kubernetes-helm

I deployed Flink via the Helm operator to a Kubernetes cluster. I enabled the `flink-s3-f2-hadoop` plugin:

```
# Source: flink-demo/templates/flink-session-cluster.yaml
apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkDeployment
metadata:
  name: flink-session-cluster
spec:
  image: flink:1.18
  flinkVersion: v1_18
  flinkConfiguration:
    taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: "2"
    s3.path.style.access: "true"
    s3.endpoint: "http://minio.minio.svc.cluster.local:80"
    s3.endpoint.region: "us-east-1"
    fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider: org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.token.DynamicTemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider
    s3.access-key: <key>
    s3.secret-key: <secret>
  serviceAccount: flink
  podTemplate:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: flink-main-container
          env:
            - name: ENABLE_BUILT_IN_PLUGINS
              value: flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.18.1.jar
  jobManager:
    resource:
      cpu: 1
      memory: 2048m
  taskManager:
    resource:
      cpu: 1
      memory: 2048m
```

Then I deployed the job:

```
apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkSessionJob
metadata:
  name: kafka-to-iceberg-job
spec:
  deploymentName: flink-session-cluster
  job:
    jarURI: <joburi>
    parallelism:  1
    upgradeMode: stateless
```

In the `pom.xml` I added the depedency `hadoop-common` as such:

```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
       <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
       <version>3.3.6</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
```

My understanding was that if you enable the plugin `flink-s3-f2-hadoop` in the `podTemplate`, then it should work, but I still get the `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration` error.

I execute the SQL statement in Java:

```
String nessieHost = System.getenv("NESSIE_HOST");
        String warehouse = System.getenv("WAREHOUSE");

        Configuration loadedConfig = GlobalConfiguration.loadConfiguration("/opt/flink/conf");
        FileSystem.initialize(loadedConfig, null);

        // set up the execution environment
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment(loadedConfig);
        // set up the table environment
        final StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(
                env,
                EnvironmentSettings.newInstance().inStreamingMode().build());

        // create the Nessie catalog
        tableEnv.executeSql(
                String.format(
                "CREATE CATALOG iceberg WITH ("
                        + "'type'='iceberg',"
                        + "'catalog-impl'='org.apache.iceberg.nessie.NessieCatalog',"
                        + "'io-impl'='org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3FileIO',"
                        + "'uri'='%s',"
                        + "'authentication.type'='none',"
                        + "'ref'='main',"
                        + "'client.assume-role.region'='us-east-1',"
                        + "'warehouse'='%s'"
                        + ")", nessieHost, warehouse));
```

Edit:

After adding the depedencies to the flink image and using it instead I now get a `The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records` error.

2nd Edit:

The current `flink-conf.yaml` in the flink session cluster pod:

```
blob.server.port: 6124
kubernetes.jobmanager.annotations: flinkdeployment.flink.apache.org/generation:2
kubernetes.jobmanager.replicas: 1
jobmanager.rpc.address: flink-session-cluster.flink-demo
kubernetes.service-account: flink
kubernetes.cluster-id: flink-session-cluster
s3.endpoint: http://minio.minio.svc.cluster.local:80
kubernetes.taskmanager.cpu.amount: 1.0
parallelism.default: 1
kubernetes.namespace: flink-demo
taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 2
fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider: org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.token.DynamicTemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider
kubernetes.rest-service.exposed.type: ClusterIP
kubernetes.jobmanager.owner.reference: uid:637395ca-dbe2-4e02-83ab-7ac5b340bed2,name:flink-session-cluster,controller:false,blockOwnerDeletion:true,apiVersion:flink.apache.org/v1beta1,kind:FlinkDeployment
kubernetes.container.image.ref: ghcr.io/steadforce/steadops/workbenches/flink-steadforce:sha-539c388
taskmanager.memory.process.size: 2 gb
kubernetes.internal.jobmanager.entrypoint.class: org.apache.flink.kubernetes.entrypoint.KubernetesSessionClusterEntrypoint
s3.endpoint.region: us-east-1
kubernetes.pod-template-file.taskmanager: /tmp/flink_op_generated_podTemplate_9353214271270240059.yaml
web.cancel.enable: false
execution.target: kubernetes-session
jobmanager.memory.process.size: 2 gb
taskmanager.rpc.port: 6122
kubernetes.jobmanager.cpu.amount: 1.0
internal.cluster.execution-mode: NORMAL
$internal.flink.version: v1_18
kubernetes.pod-template-file.jobmanager: /tmp/flink_op_generated_podTemplate_10874707070787998357.yaml
s3.path.style.access: true
s3.access-key: <key>
s3.secret-key: <secret>
```

I also have to define the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, otherwise I get the error that no credentials are provided, even though these are present in the `flink-conf.yaml`

The current erorr stacktrace:

```
2024-03-06 17:37:36,088 WARN  org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.DetachedApplicationRunner [] - Could not execute application:
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: Could not execute CreateTable in path `iceberg`.`db`.`table1`
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:372) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:105) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.DetachedApplicationRunner.tryExecuteJobs(DetachedApplicationRunner.java:84) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.DetachedApplicationRunner.run(DetachedApplicationRunner.java:70) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunHandler.lambda$handleRequest$0(JarRunHandler.java:108) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604) [?:1.8.0_402]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [?:1.8.0_402]
Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Could not execute CreateTable in path `iceberg`.`db`.`table1`
    at org.apache.flink.table.catalog.CatalogManager.execute(CatalogManager.java:1296) ~[flink-table-api-java-uber-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.table.catalog.CatalogManager.createTable(CatalogManager.java:946) ~[flink-table-api-java-uber-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.table.operations.ddl.CreateTableOperation.execute(CreateTableOperation.java:84) ~[flink-table-api-java-uber-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:1092) ~[flink-table-api-java-uber-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeSql(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:735) ~[flink-table-api-java-uber-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at com.steadforce.flink_job.App.main(App.java:72) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_402]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_402]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_402]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_402]
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    ... 7 more
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. (Service: S3, Status Code: 403, Request ID: QGRV9DABH36JCRE2, Extended Request ID: jP/TG0A8Hi9rJj4QQlP7zWW8DogQaBuG/dJQiI9aHeLbt/mSzWe9JaRP4ZCbJMpMKEumF4gqq7E=)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handleErrorResponse(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:156) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handleResponse(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:108) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handle(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:85) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handle(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:43) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler$Crc32ValidationResponseHandler.handle(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:93) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseClientHandler.lambda$successTransformationResponseHandler$7(BaseClientHandler.java:279) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:50) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:38) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:72) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:78) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:40) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.java:55) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.java:39) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:81) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:36) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:56) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:36) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.executeWithTimer(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:80) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:60) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.java:50) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.java:32) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:37) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:26) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonSyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonSyncHttpClient.java:224) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.invoke(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:103) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.doExecute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:173) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.lambda$execute$1(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:80) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.measureApiCallSuccess(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:182) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:74) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:45) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:53) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.DefaultS3Client.putObject(DefaultS3Client.java:10191) ~[bundle-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3OutputStream.completeUploads(S3OutputStream.java:438) ~[iceberg-flink-runtime-1.17-1.4.3.jar:?]
    at org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3OutputStream.close(S3OutputStream.java:265) ~[iceberg-flink-runtime-1.17-1.4.3.jar:?]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implClose(StreamEncoder.java:320) ~[?:1.8.0_402]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.close(StreamEncoder.java:149) ~[?:1.8.0_402]
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.close(OutputStreamWriter.java:233) ~[?:1.8.0_402]
    at org.apache.iceberg.TableMetadataParser.$closeResource(TableMetadataParser.java:131) ~[iceberg-flink-runtime-1.17-1.4.3.jar:?]
    at org.apache.iceberg.TableMetadataParser.internalWrite(TableMetadataParser.java:131) ~[iceberg-flink-runtime-1.17-1.4.3.jar:?]
    at org.apache.iceberg.TableMetadataParser.overwrite(TableMetadataParser.java:114) ~[iceberg-flink-runtime-1.17-1.4.3.jar:?]
    at org.apache.iceberg.BaseMetastoreTableOperations.writeNewMetadata(BaseMetastoreTableOperations.java:170) ~[iceberg-flink-runtime-1.17-1.4.3.jar:?]
    at org.apache.iceberg.BaseMetastoreTableOperations.writeNewMetadataIfRequired(BaseMetastoreTableOperations.java:160) ~[iceberg-flink-runtime-1.17-1.4.3.jar:?]
    at org.apache.iceberg.nessie.NessieTableOperations.doCommit(NessieTableOperations.java:136) ~[iceberg-flink-runtime-1.17-1.4.3.jar:?]
    at org.apache.iceberg.BaseMetastoreTableOperations.commit(BaseMetastoreTableOperations.java:135) ~[iceberg-flink-runtime-1.17-1.4.3.jar:?]
    at org.apache.iceberg.BaseMetastoreCatalog$BaseMetastoreCatalogTableBuilder.create(BaseMetastoreCatalog.java:199) ~[iceberg-flink-runtime-1.17-1.4.3.jar:?]
    at org.apache.iceberg.CachingCatalog$CachingTableBuilder.lambda$create$0(CachingCatalog.java:261) ~[iceberg-flink-runtime-1.17-1.4.3.jar:?]
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.lambda$doComputeIfAbsent$14(BoundedLocalCache.java:2406) ~[iceberg-flink-runtime-1.17-1.4.3.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.compute(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1853) ~[?:1.8.0_402]
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.doComputeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:2404) ~[iceberg-flink-runtime-1.17-1.4.3.jar:?]
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.computeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:2387) ~[iceberg-flink-runtime-1.17-1.4.3.jar:?]
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalCache.computeIfAbsent(LocalCache.java:108) ~[iceberg-flink-runtime-1.17-1.4.3.jar:?]
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalManualCache.get(LocalManualCache.java:62) ~[iceberg-flink-runtime-1.17-1.4.3.jar:?]
    at org.apache.iceberg.CachingCatalog$CachingTableBuilder.create(CachingCatalog.java:257) ~[iceberg-flink-runtime-1.17-1.4.3.jar:?]
    at org.apache.iceberg.catalog.Catalog.createTable(Catalog.java:75) ~[iceberg-flink-runtime-1.17-1.4.3.jar:?]
    at org.apache.iceberg.flink.FlinkCatalog.createIcebergTable(FlinkCatalog.java:415) ~[iceberg-flink-runtime-1.17-1.4.3.jar:?]
    at org.apache.iceberg.flink.FlinkCatalog.createTable(FlinkCatalog.java:394) ~[iceberg-flink-runtime-1.17-1.4.3.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.table.catalog.CatalogManager.lambda$createTable$18(CatalogManager.java:957) ~[flink-table-api-java-uber-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.table.catalog.CatalogManager.execute(CatalogManager.java:1290) ~[flink-table-api-java-uber-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.table.catalog.CatalogManager.createTable(CatalogManager.java:946) ~[flink-table-api-java-uber-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.table.operations.ddl.CreateTableOperation.execute(CreateTableOperation.java:84) ~[flink-table-api-java-uber-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:1092) ~[flink-table-api-java-uber-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeSql(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:735) ~[flink-table-api-java-uber-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at com.steadforce.flink_job.App.main(App.java:72) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_402]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_402]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_402]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_402]
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    ... 7 more
2024-03-06 17:37:36,117 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunHandler   [] - Exception occurred in REST handler: Could not execute application.
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `provided` scope is simply indicating when the executable is constructed that dependency will be available at runtime (i.e. generally supplied by the image that the operator-based job is running on) which in this case is the `flink:1.18` image.

You shouldn't explicitly need a reference to Hadoop as the `ENABLE_BUILT_IN_PLUGINS` configuration should get you everything that you need. I've used both the S3 and GCS-related plug-ins in the exact same manner targeting vanilla images of Flink.

Are you certain that this isn't a YAML spacing/formatting issue? Try setting the spacing such that your items appear on the same level as your `env` as seen below:

```
spec:
  ...
  podTemplate:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: flink-main-container
          env:
          - name: ENABLE_BUILT_IN_PLUGINS
            value: flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.18.1.jar
```

You should see something in the logs indicating that it is attempting to load the dependency when your pod is spinning up.

Comment: I did enable it previously, but it did not work, although I saw the log entry corresponding to the plugin. I am using now a custom image which adds the JAR depedencies manually and removed those from my job JAR. However, it seems that the s3 access is not configured properly as I get a 403 response. I added the credentials by referencing a secret as an environment variable (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY).

Comment: If it looks like access may be an issue, you may want to consider explicitly setting the credentials per [these settings](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/filesystems/s3/#configure-access-credentials) by setting the `s3.access-key` and `s3.secret-key` respectively along with configuring the plugin to talk with AWS via setting `fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider: org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.token.DynamicTemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider` on your job manager template.

Comment: Also when setting this in the flink configuration I still get the same error.

Comment: I also still get the warning at startup: 2024-03-06 16:21:37,091 INFO  
`2024-03-06 16:21:37,092 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.util.HadoopUtils                    [] - Could not find Hadoop configuration via any of the supported methods (Flink configuration, environment variables).`

Comment: And you adjusted your `ENABLE_BUILT_IN_PLUGINS` to be formatted the same as above (such that the items in the array are on the same line as the `env:` annotation? The only reason I mention this is because I've wasted hours fighting invalid/slightly off YAML before, so just wanted to confirm.

The 403 is a good sign/progress as that sounds like it's at least talking to AWS and just a matter of configuring your credentials.

Comment: Yes, I see the messages: `Linking flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.18.1.jar to plugin directory
Successfully enabled flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.18.1.jar`

Comment: See also the 2nd edit. I posted the current `flink-conf.yaml`